# react js Date-picker(react js date-picker set year range in year drop down list )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

how to disable the past years in year drop down list in react date picker?
the problem is when we click the drop down list it shows past years as well as future year.I want show the current and future years [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqf0I.png)

Comment: This may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323221/how-to-disable-past-dates-from-today-date-with-material-ui-reactjs

Comment: The code did not disable the years in year drop down but it disable the dates

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the prop `minDate` to the `DatePicker` component, and set it to the start of the current year.

```
<DatePicker
  minDate={moment().startOf('year')}
/>;
```

Comment: Will this disable previous dates or just set the start date?